# React component not re-rendering to grab Firebase data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The react code below gets a data snapshot from Firebase the first time it runs. The `this.state.term` refers to the index of a node in my Firebase Database. My `handleChoice` function does a `this.setState`, but it doesn't seem to re-render this component to grab the new data snapshot.

The value of `this.state.term` does not change under `componentDidMount`. However, when I console log it down in the render, it does.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavBar from './navbar.js';
import TermInfo from './termInfo.js';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      term: 66,          //sample term to load first
      examples: [1,2,3],
      dataNode: {},
    }
  }

componentDidMount(){
      let rootRef = firebase.database().ref('vocab/').child(this.state.term);  

    rootRef.on('value', snap => {
        this.setState({ 
          dataNode: snap.val(),
          examples: Object.assign([], snap.val().examples)
        });
      });
  }


  _handleChoice(theChosenOne){
      this.setState({ 
        term: theChosenOne 
      });  
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.term);   //this gives me the right index
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
        <NavBar choose={this._handleChoice.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
        <div className='container'>
        <div className="jumbotron"><TermInfo node={this.state.dataNode} examples={this.state.examples}/>
        <p className="App-intro">
          Enter a vocabulary term to search for and add examples! 
        </p></div>
      </div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Why does it not rerender and grab the data anew?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point is `componentDidMount` will be executed only once in the life cycle of React component, and that will be right after the initial render. Never again.

Quoting from the [official Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

---

Seems like `handleChoice` is triggered based on some events (result of some user interactions). That means we will need to call the API call on each invocation of `handleChoice`.

Also we don't need a state to maintain the chosen index. Instead let's directly use the index received by `handleChoice` to take firebase snap.

So our component will look like:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      examples: [1, 2, 3],
      dataNode: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData(66); // sample term to load first
  }

  getData(index) {
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref('vocab/').child(index);

    rootRef.on('value', snap => {
      this.setState({ 
        dataNode: snap.val(),
        examples: Object.assign([], snap.val().examples)
      });
    });
  }

  _handleChoice(theChosenOne) {
    this.getData(theChosenOne);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.term);   //this gives me the right index
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <NavBar choose={this._handleChoice.bind(this)} />
        </div>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className="jumbotron">
            <TermInfo node={this.state.dataNode} examples={this.state.examples}/>
            <p className="App-intro">
              Enter a vocabulary term to search for and add examples! 
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching me the distinction between mount and render. I'm a total noob. This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your `componentDidMount` will not be called after the state changes (`_handleChoice`) so you won't see changes in the generated html. Try setting the state and the firebase related configuration in `componentWillUpdate` instead, since you want it to always get the latest `this.state.term`. See [react's docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate).